# Elastic collisions and 90 degrees angles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

Why is it that if the angle between the two objects that collided together is 90 degrees then it must be perfectly elastic? Is there any theoretical proof other than convention?

Comment: In what reference frame? In the CM frame two objects are always moving in opposite directions. They can change direction by $90^\circ$ in inelastic collisions.  It would not be convention, it would be because you can't balance momentum without balancing energy.  Please draw a figure to show the angle you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it that if the angle between the two objects that collided together is 90 degrees then it must be perfectly elastic?

If two bodies are colliding either head on or at glancing angles one can observe  the  system from two different views:

1. Laboratory frame of reference - in which we measure normally the velocities and angles setting the event in  labs and observer is stationary.
2. Center of mass frame of reference -where the observer is moving with centre of mass of the two body and the  colliding particles approach the centre of mass and emerge out of it after collision at an angle .

For a two-particle collision, the relative velocity between the two velocity 
vectors is independent of the choice of  reference frames.

If the magnitude of the relative velocity of colliding bodies  does not change during a collision,( that is if the coefficient of restitution is equal to unity)

the change in kinetic energy before and after collision is zero,  and such situation is termed as **elastic collision** as there is no loss of  or dissipation of energy.

The angle between two colliding bodies depend on the state of collision say head on or glancing at any angle  and separating after  the hit ,

flying off in various directions even at angles nearly 180 degrees-back e.g. in back-scattering.

*so it can not be said that the angle of deflection being 90 degrees qualify* it to be a case of elastic collision -

Meaning thereby that if the angle is other than 90 degree some 'inelastic' features might be present.

Its a very particular  case of two body having equal mass 
that when they  collide  elastically  at an angle(*that is not head on*),

the angle of deflection equals to 90 degrees and the basic theory behind it  is the two conservation laws of energy and momentum which  must hold for such collisions.

In head on collision  of equal mass bodies  the angle between the two  is 180 degrees  as the body at rest takes up whole of kinetic energy from the body which hits it .

One can also  prove that the bodies of equal mass separate after the collision at right angles to each other  by making  use of the fact that momentum is a vector quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking in the *lab frame,*

For a *head-on* collision with a *stationary* object of *equal* mass, the *incident* object will stop and the *target* will move off with equal velocity. This can be generalized to the statement, "for a *head-on elastic* collision of equal masses, the velocities will always exchange."

For a *non-head-on elastic* collision between *equal masses*, you can show easily that the angle between the velocities *after* the collision will always be *90 degrees*.

So, your question is *not* exactly correct.